# add user input in database

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement this

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");
        this.name = Console.ReadLine();
        string sql1 = "insert into items values ( " + this.name ")";
        DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sql1);
```

when I try to input data through this it showing error about , unhanded exception , column name or number not found.

I am sure column name is ok and I gave it varchar(50) type. Is this method not permitted?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some error??? What error? Always include information like that, hard to tell what is going on without vital information like that, get it sorted please

Comment: your missing a + operator after this.name

Comment: thank you very much. sound silly but It was hurting my head for an hour !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First u forgot a + and second name sounds like maybe a varchar/nvarchar? than dont forget the ''

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");
this.name = Console.ReadLine();
string sql1 = "INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES ('" + this.name + "');"
DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sql1);
```

Comment: thanks. but it still showing error. I have updated the question. please read it again

Comment: i' ve also updated check, i guess u ve more columns in your table than u need to fill the whole row or select the column name explicitly!